# CTE - Reduce Stock Quantity

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I was hoping to solve the below problem with a CTE in MS SQL, but I'm hitting a brick wall.

Here's my problem.

Orders table:

```
OrderID Item    Quantity    
------------------------
1       pen     80      
2       pen     30      
3       pen     25
```

Inventory table:

```
Inv ID  Lot  Item  Quantity
---------------------------
1       001  pen   100
2       002  pen   20
3       003  pen   30
```

What I need to do is process the orders so that the first order comes out of Lot 1, the second order comes out of lot 1 and lot 2 and the third order comes of of lot 2 and lot 3.

I need to know what order comes from which lot, which means I can't just group the orders up.

So basically I need something similar to this:

```
OrderID Item  QuantityOrdered Lot  QuantityFromLot
--------------------------------------------------
1       pen   80              001  80
2       pen   30              001  20
2       pen   30              002  10
3       pen   25              002  10
3       pen   25              003  15
```

Is there a way to do this with  a CTE?  If not, what would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of a problem, C# or some other application layer solution might be the best way to go.

But it is possible to do in SQL, although it is a bit complicated.

First part of recursive CTE will take OrderID = 1 and InvID =1 and calculate for it, resulting in either `LeftInLot` > 0 or `LeftToServe` > 0.

Second part now needs two different logics based on result from first part and this is accomplished by sub-query taking both next lot and next item and using bunch of CASEs to determine which to use - and few more CASEs to provide accurate data for next recursion to continue.

It would look like this:

```
;WITH CTE_Orders AS 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY OrderID) AS RN
    FROM dbo.Orders
)
, CTE_Inventory AS 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY InvID) AS RN
    FROM dbo.Inventory
)
, CTE AS 
(
    SELECT  o.RN AS OrderRN,
            inv.RN AS InvRN,
            OrderID ,
            o.Item ,
            o.Quantity AS OrderedQuantity ,
            InvID ,
            Lot ,
            inv.Quantity AS InvQuantity,
            CASE WHEN inv.Quantity - o.Quantity > 0 THEN o.Quantity  ELSE inv.Quantity END AS ServedQuantity ,
            CASE WHEN inv.Quantity - o.Quantity > 0 THEN 0 ELSE o.Quantity - inv.Quantity END AS LeftToServe,
            CASE WHEN inv.Quantity - o.Quantity > 0 THEN inv.Quantity - o.Quantity ELSE 0 END AS LeftInLot
    FROM CTE_Orders o
    INNER JOIN CTE_Inventory inv ON o.Item = inv.Item
    --WHERE OrderID = 1 AND InvID = 1
    WHERE o.RN =1 AND inv.RN = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c1.OrderRN ELSE c2.OrderRN END AS OrderRN
            ,CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c2.InvRN ELSE c1.InvRN END AS InvRN
            ,CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c1.OrderID ELSE c2.OrderID END AS OrderID
            ,CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c1.Item ELSE c2.Item END AS Item
            ,CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c1.OrderedQuantity ELSE  c2.OrderedQuantity END AS OrderedQuantity
            ,CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c2.InvID ELSE c1.InvID END AS InvID
            ,CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c2.Lot ELSE c1.Lot END AS Lot
            ,CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c2.InvQuantity ELSE c1.LeftInLot END AS InvQuantity
            ,CASE WHEN CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c2.InvQuantity ELSE c1.LeftInLot END - CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c1.LeftToServe ELSE c2.OrderedQuantity END > 0
                  THEN CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c1.LeftToServe ELSE c2.OrderedQuantity END
                  ELSE CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c2.InvQuantity ELSE c1.LeftInLot END
             END AS ServedQuantity
            ,CASE WHEN CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c2.InvQuantity ELSE c1.LeftInLot END - CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c1.LeftToServe ELSE c2.OrderedQuantity END > 0
                  THEN 0
                  ELSE CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c1.LeftToServe ELSE  c2.OrderedQuantity END - CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c2.InvQuantity ELSE c1.LeftInLot END  
             END AS LeftToServe
            ,CASE WHEN CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c2.InvQuantity ELSE c1.LeftInLot END - CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c1.LeftToServe ELSE c2.OrderedQuantity END > 0
                  THEN  CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c2.InvQuantity ELSE c1.LeftInLot END - CASE WHEN c1.LeftInLot <=0 THEN c1.LeftToServe ELSE  c2.OrderedQuantity END 
                  ELSE 0 
             END AS LeftInLot
    FROM CTE c1
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT  o2.RN AS OrderRN,
                inv2.RN AS InvRN,
                InvID ,
                Lot ,
                inv2.Item ,
                inv2.Quantity AS InvQuantity,
                OrderID ,
                o2.Quantity AS OrderedQuantity
        FROM 
        CTE_Inventory inv2 
        INNER JOIN CTE_Orders o2 ON inv2.Item = o2.Item
    ) c2
    ON c1.Item = c2.Item AND
    ((c2.InvRN = c1.InvRN + 1 AND c2.OrderRN = c1.OrderRN AND c1.LeftInLot <= 0 ) OR (c2.OrderRN = c1.OrderRN + 1 AND c2.InvRN = c1.InvRN AND c1.LeftInLot>0))

)
SELECT * FROM CTE
ORDER BY item,OrderID
```

[SQLFiddle DEMO - old](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/61fd4/1)

**[SQLFiddle DEMO - fixed](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b3fe9/1)**

*PS: Since you can't really rely that `OrderID` and `InvID` are continuous values without any gaps - like my example has assumed (`c2.OrderID = c1.OrderID + 1`), additional complication with `ROW_NUMBER` should be done.* (fixed)

**EDIT:**

Updated solution to work with multiple items. Couple of more CTEs at the beginning to calculate ROW_NUMBERS partitioned for items and used those in JOINs instead of IDs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  This is a brilliant solution.  For some reason, I can't add more items though.  It will only give me the solution for the first item 'pen'. What do you think? I agree it would be better to do in application logic, but unfortunately I am restricted to sql only.

Comment: Probably some join or condition missing somewhere... I'll see if I can find it...

Comment: @user2417191 OK, I have updated solution to work with multiple items. Couple of more CTEs at the beginning to calculate ROW_NUMBERS partitioned for items and used those in JOINs instead of IDs. Also fix at the end to add c1.item = c2.item